# Android HttpGet: What are the exceptions should be check before execute the request?

Tags: android

Update:

```
String xmlList = null;
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            try {

                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
                HttpResponse response = null;
                response = httpClient.execute(request);
                //HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                xmlList = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

             } 
            catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                xmlList = "URL: is a malformed URL";
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                xmlList = "URL: UnsupportedEncodingException";
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                xmlList = "URL: ClientProtocolException"; 
            } catch (SocketTimeoutException  e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                xmlList = "URL: SocketTimeoutException";
            } catch (ConnectTimeoutException  e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                xmlList = "URL: ConnectTimeoutException";
            } catch (IOException e) {
                xmlList = "URL: IOException";
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            finally {
                httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            }  
            // return XML
            return xmlList;
```

**UPDATE END**

i am building an app that reads data from website and i would like to know what are the exception should be check before  execute the request?

the exceptions i am thinking of:

```
1) bad url
2) host not responding
3) time out
....
....
```

here is my code:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(SongsManager1.URL);
HttpResponse response = null;
response = httpClient.execute(request);
//HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
xmlList = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
```

Comment: How would you check if the host wasn't responding (how's that different from a timeout) before making the request?

Comment: you right host not responding and time-out is same, didn't think of that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following checks,

1. ClientProtocolException
2. IOException - This internally catches a lot of exceptions. You can check out the details in the android docs
3. URISyntaxException

You can do an network connectivity check before sending the request. Details are there in the link provided in zapl's post.

Comment: i have updated my question, is that the right way of catching the exception?

Comment: That is a lot of catching but looks fine. You need to catch them only if u want to individually do somethign different in each case. I am assuming you want to tell the user exactly why the request failed. In that case this looks fine. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if there is [network connectivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html) and if not display a message to the user that whatever the app tries is not possible.
But any further checking is unnecessary since you see what you get from the result of your query: Exceptions (e.g. bad url, timeout, ..), status codes, etc.